# Use std::all_of with boost::irange to get the loop index

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, std

I was wondering if it is possible to write an `std::all_of` statement with `boost::irange` at the same time to get the index of the item I am looping at each moment. My purpose is to refactor an expression of this kind, which looks like both of them combined:

```
for (auto instance : boost::irange(instances))
{
    if (not func(instance))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Function `func` needs an integer `instance`, I cannot refactor that function parameter. I would like to rewrite as "something" like:

```
std::all_of(..., ..., [] () { return func(instance); })
```

Is it possible? Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: There is needed one more line, where result of `irange` is stored: `auto r = boost::irange(instances);`, then the invocation of `all_of` would look like `std::all_of(std::begin(r), std::end(r), [](int instance){ return func(instance); });`.  [Coliru, demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a4470d155330de)

Comment: @rafix07 That solution is fantastic! If you post it as solution I will set it as the solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using boost, you can use [`boost::all_of`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/CXX11.html), that has an overload taking a range and a predicate, rather than two iterators and a predicate.

```
return boost::algorithm::all_of(boost::irange(instances), func);
```