# C++ equivalent to std::all_of but working with a range loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, c++20

I am trying to re-write a piece of code that currently looks like this:

```
if (nchildren > 7 && 
  parent->isChildValid(0) && 
  parent->isChildValid(1) && 
  parent->isChildValid(2) && 
  parent->isChildValid(3) && 
  ... 
  parent->isChildValid(7)
) {

}
```

It tests the `parent->isChildValid(i)` 8 times where `i`, is an index within the range [0:7] in this particular case. I was looking (as an exercise) for a way of making this more efficient (imagine the range changes later) using something that would be similar to `std::all_of` but I understand these functions only work with constructs that support iterators. So something like this:

```
std::all_of(0, 7, [&](int i){ return parent->isChildValid(i); });
```

Would of course not work. But I would like to know if there a similar/alternative options (I am sure there is)) without (of course) declaring `i` is a vector and setting its content with `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`. I am trying to avoid this as well, and look instead for something similar to `all_of` but where I could set the min and max indices (range loop kind of) over which I'd like the function to be tested for.

edit: I can't use boost.

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633183/use-stdall-of-with-boostirange-to-get-the-loop-index answer your question ?

Comment: @pasthec. Ah thank you. I saw this question indeed in my search. But yes I should have added I can't use boost)(.

Comment: Offtopic: I think there is a typo, it should be `nchildren >= 8` if last item to check has index `7`.

Comment: @MarekR Well spotted) I edited the question (and set the bound to 7) as the intention is `if num children is actually 8 thus greater than 7`. Note that I didn't write this code) (just need to maintain it right now) and also had to change the numbers as the code belongs to a private company and can't take the risk to have it identifiable. But in doing so I introduced a bug(.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++20, you can use [`views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) and [`ranges::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of) to do this

```
  if (nchildren > 8 && 
      std::ranges::all_of(std::views::iota(0, 8), 
                          [parent](auto i) { return parent->isChildValid(i); })
  ) {

  }
```

Comment: Thanks ) I had seen things like this with views but couldn't remember how they worked) Cheers )) xx

Comment: @user18490 In your example all integers are known at compile time. Is this also valid for your actual application or is this a relict from simplifying to a minimal example? If they are known at compile time, you can both speed speed up the check *and* have a working solution versions <C++20 using template meta programming. Here is a C++17 solution using fold expressions: https://godbolt.org/z/rbMEc3sqP. For older standards you would have to write a recursive template function.

Comment: @joergbrech. The range is known at compile time but not the result of the function `isChildValid(index)` which is only a result known once the program is running (it relies on data loaded from a file). But thx for pointing to this document (and solution). It's a good read).

Comment: That's fine, as long as all indices are known at compile time you can use my suggestion. The impact on performance is not gigantic: Instead of checking each index at runtime time, you dispatch to a a set of functions that have been generated at compile time, one for for every index. Each function will still be evaluated at runtime *(remove the constexpr from isChildValid)*. The bigger benefit would be from supporting older C++ standards/compilers.